# Netbeans Ghost Duplicate Class

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Experimented by drawing over the desktop, without adding any closing functionality and 'setAlwaysOnTop(true)', which had a predictable outcome - I had to restart my computer (without saving my latest change).

When I reopened Netbeans I got a "duplicate class" error (note that I only have the mentioned class) and my unsaved edition. Running the program gives me an error, dismissing it starts the pre-shutdown version (causing me to have to restart again).

I've tried deleting (through netbeans and manually) and recreating the project, and Cleaning and Building, but both with the same result. Does Netbeans store backups / XMLs somewhere, and if so how do I access / delete it? Alternatively, how do I rid of the "duplicate class" error? I could change the class name, BUT that doesn't solve anything.

- Using a brand new installation of Netbeans 8.0.2.
- Class was
  originally duplicated from another class (do I have to delete this as
  well?).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Delete Netbeans cache

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, did work, once I figured out where the cache was.